# How to find the last item with a specific value set to true in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema for a car and some activityReports for this car. Now i need to find the latest `activityReport` where `noteAlert` is set to `true`. So i thought about sth. like this

```
ActivityReport.find().where('noteAlert').equals(true).exec(function (err, activityReports) {
    activityReports.set({
        noteAlert: false
    })
    activityReports.save();
})
```

but this doesn't work.

What i need is a function that sets `showAsWarning` to false for any found object if any newer Object has it set to true in creation - i hope it is clear what i need and someone can help.

Here's a screenshot of the objects inside the database. As you can see, there are some with noteAlert set to true and now i'd like to set them all to false.

[image]

Comment: can you post some collection sample

Comment: i hope my screenshot helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making wrong query here the correct syntax for using `update` query is

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>
   }
)
```

you can find more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

So now you should try something like this

```
ActivityReport.update(
  { noteAlert: true },               //query
  { $set: { noteAlert: false}},      //update operator
  { new: true })                     // gives you new result
.exec(function (err, activityReports) {
   console.log(activityReports)
})
```

Comment: You should add a bit of description, while you add answer and code.

Looking at the question, it seems that person who asked the question is new to MongoDB.

+1 for answer :)

Comment: @HarshalYeole I have updated the answer please check